# How to pass a 2D array as argument from C# to python

Tags: c#, python

I am integrating my C# code with my python script, where **C# code is passing a 2D array as argument to Python command line**, I want to know whether the below code is the right way to do it:
The below code is used to call the python script with the array argument in C#

```
 int[,] arr = new int[3, 4] {1, 2, 3, 4}, {11, 12, 13, 14}, {21, 22, 23, 24}};
 ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
 processStartInfo.FileName = @"C:\DEV\IR_Analysis\venv\Scripts\python.exe"; 
 processStartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\DEV\IR_Analysis\BreastCancer_analysis\scratch.py"+" "+arr;
```

The below code is the python script which I am trying to run using C#, this is just for example, if this works I will use this in my actual project where C# is passing a big 2D array to python.

```py
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
```

The output of print(sys.argv[1]) should be
the set of elements of the array, but the actual output is 'System.Int32[,]'.

Comment: Start off with a simpler example, the error has to do with `System.Int32[,]` - so just pass real numbers (no decimal places, `int`s not `float`s). If you can do that we can narrow it down.

Comment: `sys.argv` is a string list, so whatever input is, `sys.argv[1][0]` will never give you 1.3. please read [python document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html) first.

Answer (score 0):

I see an issue:

`float[,] arr = new int[3, 4]`

**You've declared a Float array and are instantiating it with a Int32 array.**

Can you try this:

```
float[,] arr = new float[3, 4] {1.3, 2.2, 3.3, 4.0}, {11.2, 12.3, 13.2, 14.12}, {21.2231, 22.324567, 23.12345, 24.6789}};
```

Also acknowledge @shingo's comment, you might want to use a `sys.float_info` as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html).

Comment: yes, thank you I have tried that but problem remains same!